# gwt- is it safe to use oauth through GWT in a native or web app

Tags: gwt, oauth, gwt-2.4

I came across this library- http://code.google.com/p/gwt-oauth2/

What I am wondering about is, if I use that library, will it enable a hacker to gain access to my private clients' data? Will the hacker gain access to my facebook/other oauth2 provider's access credentials?

So should I stick to a server-side oauth2 library? Or can I go ahead and use the above library?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, that implementation is safe. IMO, there's no real reason why you would need to use a server-side library over this (in the context of safety, at least).